# InteractionCommand.addUserOption for all users not only the users that are allowed to see the channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, command

I am using Discord-Slashcommands for a few weeks and want to create a slash command to add a user to the interaction channel.

Is it possible to tell Discord.js that I want to get ALL users instead of those users that can see the channel? And if yes, how?

```js
.addUserOption(opt => opt.setName("user").setDescription("Well, what?"))
```

This code only displays the users of the current channel...

Thank you for answering!

Comment: I can mention users that can't see the channel simply by typing some characters in their username/nickname

Comment: Are you wanting all the users to show in the list when you start the command or are you wanting a command that will edit the permissions to allow a/all users to see the channel. Just asking for clarification. Because if it is the fomer, then it won't show everyone, you would just need to start typing their name, if the latter then that is possible.

Comment: @Kaspr I want to add the user to the interaction channel so that he can sees it. But the Slash-Command have to be inside the interaction channel where i can't see all users. So first of your options...

Comment: Then why not write it so that it works in any channel to add them to whatever channel you need. Adding answer to see if that helps just run the command in a channel they can currently see